# Nested tree view with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In ROR, I have a model 'Document', which may contain Section, Table, Text_field. Therefore, I have 4 models, and I use ancestry for Section as it may contain Sub-Section. Also, Table and Text_field belongs to Document, and optionally belongs to Section.
[So, structure will look like below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmCTX.png)

I could successfully iterate and print this structure as List in my view. But I would like to show the data as Treeview. Is there a way I could achieve this with Ruby on Rails?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you could print them in list, perhaps you can just change the css to look like this example? http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/

Comment: @Yewness Thanks for the response. I made it to work by collecting the data as link and passed the list to jstree plugin. Your example really helped me to achieve with css layout too, thanks!